# postgresql: INSERT INTO table_A (col_b) SELECT col_d from table_B WHERE table_B.col_c = table_A.col_a

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have 2 tables.
Table A :

```
Col_a | Col_b
--------------
abc   | [null]
def   | [null]
```

Table B :

```
Col_c | Col_d
-------------
abc   | 123
def   | 456
```

How can I insert Col_d from Table B to Col_b on Table A?
Here's what I've tried :

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (Col_b) SELECT Col_d FROM Table_B
WHERE Col.c = (SELECT Col_a FROM Table_A);
```

The WHERE conditions doesn't seem can be used that way. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
update tablea a
set col_b = b.col_d
from tableb b 
where b.col_a = a.col_c
```

For every row of `tablea` whose `col_a` can be found in `tableb`, this updates `col_b` to the value stored in `col_d` in `tableb`.